# How to stop a node and than get it to move again after 1 second?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a car that is a SKShapeNode. It is moving. When I touch it, I want to stop it for 1 second and then go back to movement.

I have this code... But it just stop, `a3` is never reached, the car don't start moving again

```
let a1 = SKAction.speedTo(0.0, duration: 0.0)
let a2 = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
let a3 = SKAction.speedTo(1.0, duration: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to move a node from point A to point B and stop it for one second when touch it.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //Create a car
        let car = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        car.name = "car"
        car.zPosition = 1
        //Start - left edge of the screen
        car.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(frame))
        //End = right edge of the screen
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(frame))
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(endPoint, duration: 10)
        car.runAction(move, withKey: "moving")
        addChild(car)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first
        if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self){

            //Get the node
            let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
            //Check if it's a car
            if node.name == "car" {

                //See if car is moving
                if node.actionForKey("moving") != nil{

                    //Get the action
                    let movingAction = node.actionForKey("moving")

                    //Pause the action (movement)
                    movingAction?.speed = 0.0

                    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
                    let block = SKAction.runBlock({
                        //Unpause the action
                        movingAction?.speed = 1.0
                    })
                    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, block ])
                    node.runAction(sequence, withKey: "waiting")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is pretty much commented. So basically, what is happening here is that:

- node movement is done by action associated with "moving" key
- when user touch the node, action associated by the "moving" key is paused; when this happen, another action called "waiting" is started "in parallel"
- "waiting" action waits for one second, and unpause the "moving" action; thus car continue with movement

Currently, when car is touched, the "moving" action is paused...So if you touch the car again, it will stay additional second where it is (the new "waiting" action will overwrite previous "waiting" action). If you don't want this behaviour, you can check if if car is waiting already, like this:

```
if node.actionForKey("waiting") == nil {/*handle touch*/}
```

Or you can check if car has stopped by checking the value of speed property of an action associated by the "moving" key.